# How do I get count of IDs based on multiple conditions on a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame (df):

| ID | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | B |

and I am trying to get the following output:

| brands | count_of_unique_ID |
| --- | --- |
| A Only | 1 |
| B Only | 1 |
| A and B | 1 |

I've tried adding an additional column 'value' and assigned 1 to each row, and created a pivot table using the following:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(values='count', index='ID', columns='Brand', aggfunc=sum)
```

| Brand | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID |  |  |
| 1 | 2.0 | NaN |
| 2 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 3 | NaN | 2.0 |

But I am stuck at this step, and not quite sure how to proceed to get the expected output mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to get the `brands` per `ID`.

Then, do a reverse counting of `ID` based on the `brands` found in step 1 using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html), as follows:

```
df2 = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
         .agg(unique_count=('Brand', 'nunique'), 
              brands=('Brand', lambda x: ' and '.join(w) if len(w:=np.unique(x)) > 1 else w[0] + ' Only'))
      )

df_final = df2.groupby('brands')['ID'].count().reset_index(name='count_of_unique_ID')
```

[`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns the unique elements sorted, so whenever you have the same set of unique brands, you still get the same combined brand even when the individual brands present in different orders under different `ID`.

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

   ID  unique_count   brands
0   1             1   A Only
1   2             2  A and B
2   3             1   B Only
```

```
print(df_final)

    brands  count_of_unique_ID
0   A Only                   1
1  A and B                   1
2   B Only                   1
```